# laravel modal display data from database

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel, modal-dialog

[image]

I need to display exactly like this. it is currently working right now but if there is alternative and cleaner method pls. post.

I will post exactly how this work. I have  a feeling that there is more way to display data.

this is all in one blade. let's call it **table.blade.php**

this is the running code right now.

table code.

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:35%;">Name</th>
                    <th>Contact Person</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Phone Number</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>View</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($data as $value)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $value['name'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value['contact_person'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value['email'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value['phone_number'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ date('F d, Y h:i:s a',strtotime($value['created_at'])) }}</td>
  <!--view button--><td><button data-id="{{ $value['id'] }}" class="btn btn-block btn-info" onClick="open_container2(this);" ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i> View </button></td>
                    <td><a href="{{ url('dashboard/delete', [Hashids::encode($value -> id)]) }}"><button class="btn btn-block btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash"></i> Delete</button></a></td>
                </tr>
                    @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

if I click **view** button it goes to this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function open_container2(id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:'{{ url('dashboard/view') }}',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: { id:id.getAttribute('data-id') },
            success: function(data){
                if(data.success)
                {
                    $('#date').html(data.data.created_at);
                    $('#name').html(data.data.name);
                    $('#corp').html(data.data.name);
                    $('#cp').html(data.data.contact_person);
                    $('#email').html(data.data.email);
                    $('#phone').html(data.data.phone_number);
                    $('#link').attr('href', 'dashboard/xlsx/' + data.data.id);
                    $('#link2').attr('href', 'dashboard/edit/' + data.data.id);
                    $('#myModal2').modal('show');
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

after retrieving all the data it shows the blue modal just like exactly at the top.

**modal**

```
<div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="box-header with-border">
                                <h3 class="box-title" id="corp">
                                </h3>
                            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                            <div class="box-body">

                                <dl class="dl-horizontal ajax">
                                    <dt>Posted Date</dt>
                                    <dd id="date"></dd>
                                    <dd>&nbsp;</dd>
                                    <dt>Name</dt>
                                    <dd id="name"></dd>
                                    <dd>&nbsp;</dd>
                                    <dt>Contact Person</dt>
                                    <dd id="cp"></dd>
                                    <dt>Email</dt>
                                    <dd id="email"></dd>
                                    <dt>Phone Number</dt>
                                    <dd id="phone"></dd>
                                </dl>
                            </div><!-- /.box-body -->

                    </div><!-- ./col -->
```

now if I could display all the data without going through the something like this:

```
$('#date').html(data.data.created_at);
                    $('#name').html(data.data.name);
                    $('#corp').html(data.data.name);
                    $('#cp').html(data.data.contact_person);
                    $('#email').html(data.data.email);
                    $('#phone').html(data.data.phone_number);
```

that would be great.

I want to display it something like this.

example of what I want.

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal ajax">
    <dt>Posted Date</dt>
    <dd>{{ $value['created_at'] }}</dd>
    <dd>&nbsp;</dd>
    <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd>{{ $value=['name'] }}</dd>
    <dd>&nbsp;</dd>
    <dt>Contact Person</dt>
    <dd>{{ $value['contact_person'] }}</dd>
    <dt>Email</dt>
    <dd>{{ $value['email'] }}</td>
    <dt>Phone Number</dt>
    <dd>{{ $value['phone_number'] }}</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't really get your question. Can you describe your problem in two/three line at the end. Currently its quite scattered and hard to understand. Thanks for your patience and effort.

Comment: I updated the post sir. this is the best explanation I can give. If it is still not understandable I could rephrase. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

**Laravel constraint**

The functionality which are trying to achieve is not possible in Laravel. There is no direct link between Laravel code and jquery code. You have to use jquery to update the DOM like you are doing.

**All the way AngulaJS**

The best you can get to achieve this type of functionality is to use AngularJS. Here is how you will do in AngularJS

1. Make async ajax call to API to get data
2. Load data in model (or scope)
3. Use the scope object in HTML
4. The model (scope) is two way binded so any changes from JS will
   promptly reflected in HTML and vice versa

**Deep dive**

For detailed info you can [read here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

Comment: looks like I'm at the end of the road. Thank you for giving me an alternative way through angular, I appreciate it.

Comment: You can wait for other answers and if some better answer comes along you can mark it as accepted answer. Otherwise I think its the only way to go.